# How to hide color/size elements in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do I hide the color or size if their values are empty?

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cBJa.jpg)

```
<p class="lx-sizes">
                        <span>SIZE :</span> @foreach ($produit->sizes as $size)
                        <a data-id="{{ $size->name }}" href="javascript:;" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">{{ $size->name }}</a> @endforeach
                    </p>
                    <p class="lx-colors">
                        <span>COLOR :</span> @foreach ($produit->colors as $color)
                        <a data-id="{{ $color->name }}" href="javascript:;" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">{{ $color->name }}</a> @endforeach
                    </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surround it in an if statement:

```
@if($produit->colors->count())
<p class="lx-colors">
    <span>COLOR :</span>
    @foreach ($produit->colors as $color)
        <a data-id="{{ $color->name }}" href="javascript:;" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">{{ $color->name }}</a> 
    @endforeach
</p>
@endif
```

Do the same for the size, using `$produit->sizes->count()`.